# Ideal Gas Law paradox

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, ideal-gas

When volume is not constant and temperature increases, pressure remains constant. ie. Charles Law.

But if you have a manometer and you heat the gas flask, volume of gas in gas flask increases since liquid level drops on the side of gas flask. But, pressure also increases.

Does this not contradict Charles Law?

Comment: Are you saying that there is liquid in the flask with the gas?

Answer (score 2):

According to Wikipedia, Charles law states:

> When the pressure on a sample of a dry gas is held constant, the Kelvin temperature and the volume will be in direct proportion

Meaning the law doesn't say that when heating something, its pressure doesn't change, but the opposite: ***if*** you guarantee that the pressure doesn't change, so a change in temperature will change the volume.